# Unexpected character error when filtering in R

Tags: r, filtering

I have a data set called Data_T_2Partner that has a column titled "Order" which contains strings. I want to filter out rows in which the comments entry contains the word OTW

I read the data into R from an xlsx file. I have tried this function:

```
Data_T_2Partner <- Data_T_2Partner %>%
filter("OTW", Order Channel Code)
```

However, I get an error that says:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"Data_T_2Partner <- Data_T_2Partner %>%
filter("OTW", Order)

#   Item   Item description Order
#    1         Mocha            OTW
#    2         Venti            MOP
#    3         Blonde           OTW
#    4         Iced             CAFE
```

Comment: It would be much better if you could share a reproducible piece of your data, so that others can help you more efficiently.

Comment: What is the name of the column you would like to put a filter on?

Comment: I added some sample data. Sorry i am new to stack overflow. I want to filter the column Order

Comment: No it's ok. Just whenever you would like to ask a question bear in mind to share a reproducible piece of your data with this code : `dput(head(my_data_frame))` it will create a reproducible data frame so that others can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like refer to your new column name, you have to surround it with back ticks. That's because this naming is against R's naming conventions. So I think you can use the following code for filtering:

```
library(dplyr)

Data_T_2Partner <- Data_T_2Partner %>%
filter(`Order Channel Code` == "OTW")
```

I assumed that you already changed your column name to this.

Answer (score 0):

```r
Data_T_2Partner <- Data_T_2Partner %>%
    filter(Order == "OTW")
```

Comment: I renamed my column to Order Channel Code and continue to get the same error

Comment: As a general recommendation: It would be better if the column names (or variables in general) don't contain whitespaces.